# The gradient of the form $\text{Tr}\left(W(I+X^HAX)^{-1}\right)$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I read a paper and the paper shows the following:
$$\nabla_{B_k} \text{Tr}\left( W_k E_k \right)=-H^H_kR^{-1}H_kB_kE_kW_kE_k,$$
where $E_k=\left( I+B^H_k H^H_kR^{-1}H_kB_k \right)^{-1}$.
Here,
$H_k \in \mathbb{C}^{Q \times P}$,
$B_k \in \mathbb{C}^{P \times Q}$,
$W_k \in \mathbb{C}^{Q \times Q}$
$R^{-1}$ is $Q \times Q$ hermitian matrix that is independent of $B_k$. However, I try to derive the gradient myself and instead I obtain
$$\nabla_{B_k} \text{Tr}\left( W_k E_k \right)=-E_kH^H_kR^{-1}H_kB_kE_kW_k.$$
My approach is the following. I use the fact that:
$$E_k=E_k^H$$
$$\partial \text{Tr} \left( W_kE_k^H\right)=W_k^H,$$
$$\partial J^{-1}=-J^{-1} \frac{\partial J}{\partial B_k} J^{-1},$$
$$J = I+B^H_k H^H_kR^{-1}H_kB_k,$$
I apply the chain rule and thus obtain
$$\frac{\partial \text{Tr} \left( W_kE_k\right)}{\partial B_k}=
-W_k^H E_k B^H_k H^H_kR^{-1}H_k E_k.$$
Am I doing something wrong somewhere? Can someone kindly help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(X) = \operatorname{tr}(W(I+X^HAX)^{-1})$ (correcting  the error in the question title). Use the chain rule through to find the map derivative

$\mathrm d_X  f=\operatorname{tr}\left(W\cdot \mathrm d_X\left[(I+X^HAX)^{-1}\right]\right)=\operatorname{tr}\left(-W\cdot ()^{-1}\cdot d_X\left[()\right] \cdot ()^{-1}\right) = -\operatorname{tr}\left(W\cdot (I+X^HAX)^{-1}\cdot (X^HA\mathrm d_XX+\mathrm (d_XX)^H A X) \cdot (I+X^HAX)^{-1}\right)$

The $\mathrm d_XX$ is the identity map of course and is serving here as a placeholder: that's where an argument $h$ of this linear map gets plugged in. Let's also rename variables $B=X$, $G=A$ and $E=(I+B^HGB)^{-1}$. We now have

$\mathrm d_B  f[h] = -\operatorname{tr}\left(W\cdot E\cdot (B^HGh+h^H G B) \cdot E\right)$

We now use the cyclic, linearity, and transpose properties of trace:
$-\mathrm d_B  f[h] = \operatorname{tr}\left(EWE\cdot (B^HGh+h^H G B)\right)=\operatorname{tr}(EWEB^HG\cdot h)+\operatorname{tr}(EWE\cdot h^HGB)=\operatorname{tr}((EWEB^HG+(GBEWE)^H)\cdot h))=\langle(EWEB^HG)^H+GBEWE,h\rangle_F$

where we also brought in the definition of the Frobenius inner product. Therefore the "gradient" is $-((EWEB^HG)^H+GBEWE)$.

In your case $G^H=G$ and $E^H=E$ so the answer is indeed $-GBE(W^H+W)E$

Answer (score 1):

Let's reduce the clutter by dropping the $k$ subscripts.

Then define the hermitian matrices
$$\eqalign{
G &= H^HR^{-1}H \;&=\; G^H \\
F &= I+B^H GB \;&=\; F^H \\
E &= F^{-1} \;&=\; E^H  \\
dE &= -E\,dF\,E \\
}$$
Let's also use a colon as a convenient product notation for the trace, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= {\rm Tr}(AB^T) \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij} B_{ij} \\
A^*:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
Write the objective function using the above notation.

Then calculate its differential and gradient $\big($treating $B^*$ as independent of $B\big)$.

[**NB:** After re-reading the comments, I conjugated the function]
$$\eqalign{
\phi^* &= W^*:E \\
d\phi^* &= W^*:dE \\
 &= -W^*:E\,dF\,E \\
 &= -E^*W^*E^*:dF \\
 &= -E^*W^*E^*:B^HG\,dB \\
 &= -G^*B^*E^*W^*E^*:dB \\
 &= -(GBEWE)^*:dB \\
\frac{\partial\phi^*}{\partial B}
 &= -(GBEWE)^*\\
}$$
This is the *complex conjugate* of your report of the result from the paper.

Therefore I assume that the paper actually claims that
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial B^*} &= -GBEWE \\
}$$
and you simply misread it.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I am a little confuse with the derivation. I wonder should I change all the transpose to conjugate transpose instead. For example, the line: $-E^HWE^H:dB^TG^*\,B^* \\$  should be $-E^HWE^H:dB^HG^*\,B^* \\$ and $A:B=\text{Tr}\left( A B^H \right)$.

Comment: @M.A.N Don't change the definition of the colon product! The underlying trace function is invariant with respect to the transpose, but not wrt to the hermitian or complex conjugate, i.e. $${\rm Tr}(A)={\rm Tr}(A^T)\ne{\rm Tr}(A^H)={\rm Tr}(A^*)$$ Instead, I would suggest translating each line of my post into the equivalent trace relationship by _transposing_ the matrix on the RHS of the colon. And using the cyclic property of the trace.

Comment: Alright, I have tried doing so but I still encounter a minor problem and I would like to check with you. Please find the following:
$$\begin{aligned}
-G^TB^*E^TW^TE^T:dB
&=\rm{Tr}(-G^TB^*E^TW^TE^T dB^T)\\
&=\rm{Tr}(-(G^HBE^HW^HE^H)^* dB^T)\\
&=\rm{Tr}(-(GBEW^HE)^* dB^T)\\
&=-(GBEW^HE)^*: dB\\
&\neq-(GBEW^TE)^*: dB\\
\end{aligned}$$
Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: You are correct. Good catch! So the disagreement with the paper is more than a simple conjugation error.

Comment: @M.A.N I started to update my answer to fix the error that you spotted, but halfway through that effort I came to a different conclusion.

Comment: Thanks Greg for studying my question. I agree with you that:
$$\rm{Tr}(A)=\rm{Tr}(A^T) \neq \rm{Tr}(A^*)=\rm{Tr}(A^H).$$
Furthermore, I managed to obtain the answer as given in the paper. Based on your idea, I redefine $A:B=\rm{Tr}(AB^H)$ since $\rm{Tr}(AA^H)=\big\|A\big\|^2_F$ for a complex matrix. Using a similar line of argument, I have:
$$\begin{aligned}
\phi&=W:E^H\\
d\phi&=W:dE^H\\
&=W:-E^HdF^HE^H\\
&=-EWE:dF^H\\
&=-EWE:dBG^HB^H\\
&=-GBEWE:dB
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Nevertheless, I am not very satisfied with this answer because as I check the gradient numerically I obtain $\nabla_B \rm{Tr}(WE)=-GBE(W+W^H)E$ where this expression is obtained via a matrix cookbook: https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf, page 14, eq(125). I am not sure how the authors obtained the expressions. Perhaps you will understand. BTW, do you mind to provide me some references on the colon method that you just introduced above? I am not aware of such method and would like to learn more of it, if possible.